# Amazon Transcribe: transcribe multiple languages in the same media file

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-transcribe

I've a video file in which the speaker is speaking in more than one language (e.g. English and Italian). I want my subtitles/transcriptions to contain text in both of these languages. After reading the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transcribe/latest/dg/API_StartTranscriptionJob.html), I came to know that Amazon Transcribe offers automatic language detection but it doesn't specify what happens if more than one language are a part of the same media file? Also I couldn't find a separate configuration where I can enable multiple language transcriptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var job = await client.StartTranscriptionJobAsync(new StartTranscriptionJobRequest
{
    IdentifyMultipleLanguages = true,
    Media = new Media
    {
        MediaFileUri = mediaUploadFileUri
    },
    OutputBucketName = _bucketName, // Your Bucket Name
    TranscriptionJobName = _transcriptionJobName // Your transcribe job name
});
```

One of LanguageCode, IdentifyLanguage, or IdentifyMultipleLanguages: If you know the language of your media file, specify it using the LanguageCode parameter; you can find all valid language codes in the Supported Languages table. If you do not know the languages spoken in your media, use either IdentifyLanguage or IdentifyMultipleLanguages and let Amazon Transcribe identify the languages for you.